# Why my Django form is not raising validation error?

Tags: python, django, validation, python-3.x, django-forms

Following is my form code:

```
class ConfirmEmailForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    subscribe = forms.IntegerField()
    code = forms.CharField(max_length=80)

    def clean_subscribe(self):
        value = bool(self.cleaned_data['subscribe'])
        self.cleaned_data['subscribe'] = value
        return value

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ConfirmEmailForm, self).clean()
        email = cleaned_data['email']
        code = cleaned_data['code']
        user = User.objects.filter(username=email).first()
        if not user:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Email not found')
        self.cleaned_data['user'] = user
        if user.emailverification.is_key_expired():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Link expired, please regenerate')
        if not user.emailverification.key == code:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid Link')
        return cleaned_data
```

I am using this form for a GET request. Now when I send the request without `email` field, I was expecting that the error will be raised at `cleaned_data`, however it doesn't raise any error and rather I get `KeyError` at next line.

Obviously it will raise an `KeyError` since it is absent. But my question, why the error is not being raised at `super(ConfirmEmailForm, self).clean()` itself.

Here is the full traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/user/confirm/?code=g&subscribe=1

Django Version: 1.9.6
Python Version: 3.5.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'nightreads',
 'nightreads.posts',
 'nightreads.user_manager']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/avi/.virtualenvs/nightreads/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/avi/.virtualenvs/nightreads/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/avi/.virtualenvs/nightreads/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/avi/.virtualenvs/nightreads/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/avi/Documents/code/nightreads/nightreads/user_manager/views.py" in get
  54.         if form.is_valid():

File "/Users/avi/.virtualenvs/nightreads/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  161.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "/Users/avi/.virtualenvs/nightreads/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  153.             self.full_clean()

File "/Users/avi/.virtualenvs/nightreads/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  363.         self._clean_form()

File "/Users/avi/.virtualenvs/nightreads/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_form
  390.             cleaned_data = self.clean()

File "/Users/avi/Documents/code/nightreads/nightreads/user_manager/forms.py" in clean
  30.         email = cleaned_data['email']

Exception Type: KeyError at /user/confirm/
Exception Value: 'email'
```

Why it is happening? And how do I solve this? What is the proper way to access validated and cleaned data in `clean`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the clean method gets an error it will add it to the list of errors, it doesn't raise it.

You can find the line of code [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L395).

```
        except ValidationError as e:
            self.add_error(name, e)
```

You could resolve it by using `cleaned_data.get('email')` which will return `None` if the value isn't found - which you can then check against.

Comment: well if I want to access multiple variables, so I have to get each of them and see if they are not null?

Comment: @avi - Yes, or just submit the whole form and not sections of it

Comment: well its a `GET`, I can't really make sure users are not editing the URL

Answer (score 3):

Before doing `cleaned_data['email']` check any error existing or not.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(ConfirmEmailForm, self).clean()

    if any(self.errors):
        return self.errors

    email = cleaned_data['email']
    code = cleaned_data['code']
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's because when you use the clean method Any ValidationError raised by this method will not be associated with a particular field;

Try to create a custom except for this.